# JQuery, is there a way to select all elements on the page with a specific attribute?

Tags: jquery

Assuming I create something like:

```
<div>
<p myAttribute='Hello'>Text</p>
..
</div>
```

I then want to find on my page, all elements that have myAttribute, regardless of what they are. How do I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [has-attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/), for example:

```
$("[myAttribute]")
```

To get elements with that attribute with that specific value, use the [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), like this:

```
$("[myAttribute='Hello']")
```

[You can find the full list of Attribute Selectors available here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/).

Comment: @SLC - I'm not following...what do you mean by nested search?  The above will find all elements in the page with the attribute, regardless of where they are, do you want to look inside something specific?

Comment: It steps through all of the DOM elements on the page, but you can limit the scope by using the context: `$('[myAttribute]', '#container');`

Comment: Great, that's fine. I wasn't sure if it just searched one tier of children or not. Thanks.

Comment: @Krof - `$('#container [myAttribute]');` would be a bit cheaper/more terse ;)

Comment: True, but it's faster if you already have a local value of `$('#container')` stored somewhere that you can just plug in there. :)

Comment: @Krof - that depends on the browser...the internal selector engine can kick in here making one selector either way :)