# Select element by attribute only

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery, is there a way to select all elements on the page with a specific attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333720/jquery-is-there-a-way-to-select-all-elements-on-the-page-with-a-specific-attrib)

My code

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $("No idea what to write here").remove();
            });
        </script>

        <button data-fun="a">Remove</button>
        <div data-fun="b">Remoave</div>
        <span data-fun="c">Remdove</span>
        <strong data-fun="d">Rdemove</strong>
        <b data-fun="e">Remosve</b>
        <p data-fun="f">Remoe</p>
        <div>Not Remove</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to remove all the elements that have the `data-fun` attribute no matter what the element is and value of `data-fun` is.

Comment: Brilliant Question by the way +1 :P favorite bit is `$("No idea what to write here")` :)

Comment: Take the time to read the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/), especially about [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/JfBvG/

**code**

```
$(function(){
$("[data-fun]").remove();
});​
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
$(function() {
     $("[data-fun]").remove();
})
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/MyUtF/)**

Comment: @Webtecher could you please explain problem of my answer? Just for my clarity.

Comment: +1 for being the first to respond with the correct answer.

Comment: i believe in equality and you get too many upvotes than tats_innit

Comment: @Webtecher yup, great, "hat off"!