# Jquery - How to override a label with a for attribute?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This seems a silly question but I'm not getting how to do this. I have this HTML:

```
<label for="id_form-1-somefield">some name</label>
<label for="id_form-2-somefield">some name 2</label>
...
```

I need to change the string "some name" in the label. How can I build a selector change the value "some name"?

Any clues?

Comment: Use the attribute selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery, is there a way to select all elements on the page with a specific attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333720/jquery-is-there-a-way-to-select-all-elements-on-the-page-with-a-specific-attrib)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $("label[for='id_form-1-somefield']")
```

Will do as you ask.  Remember that a selector on an id will be fastest, so if you can make a unique id and select on that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("label[for='id_form-1-somefield']").text("your new text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Append an id to those fields e.g. `someid`
And then

```
$("label[for='id_form-1-somefield']").val("some value");
```

or

```
$("#someid").val("some value");
```

Comment: `label` elements have `text()` or `html()`, not `val()`

Comment: Why does the OP have to add an ID? Your selector does not even use it.

Comment: I'm sorry I mixed my two ideas and didn't finish one of them

Answer (score 0):

```
$("label[for='id_form-1-somefield']")
and
$("label[for='id_form-2-somefield']")
```