# Selecting XML Field based on "var" Value (JQuery and Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, find, append

I am receiving XML back with the following format:

```
<x type="result">
<field type="text-single" label="When" var="when">
<field type="text-single" label="Where" var="where">
....
```

I know how to find the `<x ... >` and make changes, e.g.,

```
$(xml).find("x").append($(xml2));
```

What I need to do now though it find the field with var="where" and append `<value>LDN</value>`.

The trouble I have is finding a way to select the specific field with var="where", any advice please?

Thank you!

Kind Regards,

Gary Shergill

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery, is there a way to select all elements on the page with a specific attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333720/jquery-is-there-a-way-to-select-all-elements-on-the-page-with-a-specific-attrib)

Answer (score 3):

Use an attribute selector:

```
$(xml).find("x field[var='where']").append($(xml2));
```

[Here is a link to the jQuery Selector documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: @adeneo ha ha well I've had extra coffee this morning :)

Comment: Amazing, worked great! Thanks =) Spent a while looking for that link too, will be a massive help.